# Как положить в базу данных текущее время и дату, получив их лишь единожды

Tags: c#, sql-server

Есть таблица в базе данных SQL Server, есть SSIS flow. Первая колонка в таблице называется "EXTRACTION_ID", и лежать в ней должны дата и текущее время в формате "20171115173543". Но, так как записей много, на заполнение таблицы уходит время, и в результате значения в колонке постоянно увеличиваються, так как мы постоянно вызываем методы для получения текущих даты/времени. То есть, выходит вот так:
 - 20171115173543
 - 20171115173544
 - 20171115173545 и так далее.

[image: How it works now DB]

Мне же необходимо, что бы в столбце EXTRACTION_ID лежало постоянное значение, например 20171115173543.

Как это работает сейчас:
[image: How it works now.]

Возможно ли осуществить это?

P.S. Кроме того, в рамках одного флоу, я имею несколько таких таблиц, и значения для колонки EXTRACTION_ID для них должны быть одинаковыми. Возможно, есть вариант как положить текущие дату и время в переменную единожды, только при нажатии на "Execute Package"?

Comment: У вас стоит метка C# на вопросе, приведите свой код, посмотрим. Вы вставку делаете из C#-кода? Почему бы просто не сохранить один раз дату-врем на клиентской стороне в переменную? Какую технологию работы с БД используете?

Comment: 1) C# метка, потому что использую SSIS, кода, который бы влиял на эту переменную, нет (всё, что влияет, на скриншотах). 
2) Ну, у меня конкретная таска - "столбец в БД, ячейки которого наполненны датой и временем на момент заполнения таблицы, все одинаковые, тип столба - bigint".
3) Для работы с БД использую OLE DB и SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вот так:

```
DECLARE @Extraction_ID NUMERIC

SELECT @Extraction_ID = format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

В отличии в C#, в SQL значение в переменную ложится лишь однажды, не вызывая постоянно метод getCurrentDate(); Таким образом, положив значение текущего времени однажды, можно доставать значение не боясь, что дата и время будет изменятся.